# How to have geb static content recognized form test script

Tags: spock, geb

The example:

Page Class

```
Page TestPage extends Page{
    static at = {blah blah....} 

    static content = {
        someVar {$(By.id("someId"))}
    }
}
```

Script:

```
class Test extends GebReportingSpec{

    def "some Feature Methods"(){
        when:
        def page1 = at TestPage
        page1.someVar.click() //In intellij "someVar" shows as unrecognized
    }
}
```

According to what I have read and researched, in the example above, `someVar` should autocomplete and be recognized, but it is not. the code still runs and works correctly but `someVar` still comes up as unrecognized by the autocompiler in Intellij.

The only way I can have the variable be recognized is by creating a getter method for `someVar`

When I see the answer to this question: [Geb authoring support within Intellij-IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220591/geb-authoring-support-within-intellij-idea)

I assume that what I am attempting to do should work but it does not. is there a way to have the static content autocomplete without creating getter methods?

Edit: 
Also wanted to add that in my case I am getting the page objects from a jar file. Both the binaries and the sources jars are downloaded and recognized.

Comment: I'm struggling to replicate your problem with a fresh (latest) install of intelliJ CE.  Page elements are resolving successfully using identical code.  geb version 1.1.1, groovy version 2.4.12.  I appreciate this might not be too helpful!

Comment: Also assumed "Page TestPage extends Page" was a typo and you meant "class TestPage extends Page".

Comment: @Rushby Yes that is what I meant. One thing to note (and I will edit my question accordingly) is that I am grabbing my pages from a .jar file, but do note that I am grabbing both the binaries and the sources. and Intellij is able to recognize said sources

Comment: I think that the fact you're getting your pages in a binary form from a jar file might be a factor here. I'd suggest creating an issue in IntelliJ's tracker.

Comment: @erdi Will do, but wanted to make sure you noticed that I said I have both the binaries and sources,and when I "step through" it takes me to the sources not the binaries

Comment: Also I am not really sure how to phrase my ticket for intellij issue tracker.  how can I prove that its an Intelij issue and not a Geb issue.

Comment: Yes, I’ve noticed that you mentioned having both binary and sources set up in IntelliJ but as far as I know, sources are used only for navigation and showing code to tge developer but symbols are resolved from jar if that’s how a dependency is resolved (as in it not being a dependency to another module in the same source tree/project). I’ve recently provided improvements to IntelliJ’s support for Geb and I’m sure that whoever picks up the ticket will understand that it’s a problem with IntelliJ’s support for content definition of Geb pages coming from a jar and not a problem with Geb.

Comment: @erdi Created a ticket for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195500