# How do I create a "getter" for my modules (How do you instantiate a Module Object using a Navigator?)

Tags: spock, geb

I am trying to make it so that all of my page and module references can autocomplete in intellij.

Due to some sort of bug I am unable to do this like one normally would. (see here for more details: [How to have geb static content recognized form test script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688315/how-to-have-geb-static-content-recognized-form-test-script) )

In order to work around the above mentioned bug. I opted to create "getters" for all of my static content.

for example:

The Page:

```
class MyPage extends Page{
    static content = { 
        tab {$(By.xpath("somexpath")}
    }

    Navigator tab(){
        return tab
    }
}
```

The Script:

```
//imagine we are in the middle of a feature method here
def test = at MyPage
test.tab().click()
```

So all of the above code works as I expect it to, and I want to redo my pages like this so that I can have autocomplete from the script side. Problems occur when I try to use this same technique for modules.

For example:

```
class MyPage extends Page{
    static content = { 
        mod {module(new MyModule())}
    }

    MyModule mod(){
        return mod
    }
}
```

If I try and access mod from the script like so

```
//imagine we are in the middle of a feature method here
def test = at MyPage
test.mod().someModContentMaybe().click()
```

I get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'MyPage' -> mod: 'MyModule' with class 'geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent' to class 'MyModule'
```

If I try to do the following in the page object:

```
class MyPage extends Page{
    static content = { 
        mod {module(new MyModule())}
    }

    MyModule mod(){
        return new MyModule()
    }
}
```

I get the following error when attempting to access the module from the script:

```
geb.error.ModuleInstanceNotInitializedException: Instance of module class MyModule has not been initialized. Please pass it to Navigable.module() or Navigator.module() before using it.
```

I guess it wants me to take an instantiated Navigator Object and and to call `module(MyModule)` but I am not sure how this works or how one would decide which Navigator Object to call module from.

All in all, I just want to be able to autocomplete module Names and static content from my scripts.

Comment: Maybe you want to mention which IDE and version you have problems with. Chances are that there is someone who can help you find out how to configure the IDE and the project so as to enable tab completion without any synthetic getters.

Comment: Idid just create a ticket for this issue on the Intellij bug tracker. Still would like to figure out a work around in the meantime.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a `GroovyCastException` when returning content that contains a module from a method whose return type is a class which extends `geb.Module` because navigators and modules returned from content definitions get wrapped in [`geb.content.TemplateDerivedPageContent`](http://gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/content/TemplateDerivedPageContent.html).

You can unwrap them using the `as` keyword as explained in the manual section about [unwrapping modules returned from the `content` DSL](http://gebish.org/manual/current/#unwrapping-modules-returned-from-the-code-content-code-dsl). So, for one of your examples it would look like this:

```
MyModule mod(){
    mod as MyModule
}
```

Comment: That is interesting Erdi. I will have to try out the `as` key word, as I have yet to use it.

Comment: Accepted this one after testing it out. This one doesn't require instantiating a Navigator object, so I am going with this one.

Answer (score 3):

The [Book of Geb's section about modules](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#modules) answers your question. You should not manually call the module's constructor, but instead instead use the syntax described right at the beginning of the chapter. This solution gets rid of the exception and also solves the code completion problem for me:

```java
static content = { 
  mod { module MyModule }
}
```

Now that the exception is gone here is how to add the getter you asked for:

```java
def myModule() { mod }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you `content` block. `Module`s are defined via `Navigator`s' `module` method:

```
static content = {
    mod { $("div.module").module(MyModule)
}
```

So no constructor calling required.

Comment: Although I didn't do exactly what you have here. This essentially the correct answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. Read the book of Geb its really a well written documentation.